# custom maximised windows-size in opensuse 13.2 (KDE)

Tags: kde, opensuse, window-manager, desktop

Is there a way to maximise a window in openSUSE (KDE) to a custom size?

There are obviously ways to fully maximise, or use a full quarter or half of a screen quickly. What I'd like however is using say 3/4 of a screen in horizontal direction, and full height vertically - without having to resize my picture using the mouse each and every time.

With bigger monitors, this is becoming more and more of an issue for me...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the terminal program you're using, you can specify the geometry and placement of the window.

For example:

```
xterm -geometry 96x24-0+0
```

The man pages will tell you more.  The xterm program is unusual in that the geometry is in characters rather than pixels.

-E

Comment: Thanks, but this is unfortunately not quite what I am looking for, as it is program specific...

Comment: The "-geometry" option is supported on most X programs.  It's just that for terminals (and emacs) it means something different.  This link has some other options.

[link](http://fixunix.com/xwindows/91223-resizing-xterm-terms-pixels-instead-chars.html)
http://fixunix.com/xwindows/91223-resizing-xterm-terms-pixels-instead-chars.html

Comment: Bennet: I think we are still misunderstanding each other: I am not looking for a way to start a program/window with a certain window size. Instead, I am looking for a way to "maximise" a(ny) window to a pre-defined size (e.g. 3/4-screen), so I can change back and forth between "3/4-maximised" and "not maximised".

Comment: I now understand. I'm pretty sure that ICCCM would support such a thing, but I don't know that anyone has written the code to do so.  I think the place to start looking is the documentation for `Kwin`, the default KDE window manager.